# CakePHP function not updating table

Tags: database, cakephp

hi all when trying to update my database, this function isn't grabbing the id from the table and it isn't updating that line in the table. Its also throwing an error with

```
$this->Relationship->id = $this->request->data['id'];
```

here is the function in its entirety

```
public function approve($id=null){
        $this->Relationship->id = $id;
        if($this->request->is('get')){
        $this->request->data=$this->Relationship->read();}
        $this->Relationship->id = $this->request->data['id'];
        if($this->Relationship->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your Relationship has been updated.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'request'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }
    }
```

here is form/view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Relationship', array('action'=>'approve'));
echo $this->Form->input('expirydate',array('label'=>'Expiry Date: ', 'class' => 'dateclass')); 
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

?>
```

what I'm trying to do with this function is grab a the id, and edit two fields in that entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function approve($id=null){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Relationships');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';

        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Relationship->read(NULL, $id);

        } else {
        //sets active to 1
         $this->Relationship->read(null, $id);
         $this->Relationship->set(array('active' => true,));
        if ($this->Relationship->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'request'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to change a tinyint from 0=>1 in the database.The other issue I had was with my request view, it was not passing the id to the approve function. Once I changed the code to this it worked

```
<?php foreach($Relationships as $relationship):?>
                    <tr> 

                        <td align='center'><?php echo $relationship['Relationship']['partyone']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $relationship['Relationship']['partytwo']; ?></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($relationship['Relationship']['partyone'], array('action'=>'approve', $relationship['Relationship']['id'])); ;?>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$this->request->data['Relationship']['id'];` if you setup your form correctly. Also, you can just do

```
$this->Relationship->create($this->request->data);
$this->Relationship->save()
```

Comment: could you please go into further detail on how id set up my form?